# How can I check if an object exists in the global environment and then remove it from within a function?

Tags: r, function, environment-variables

There are some similar questions to this, but the answers provided are tailored to those questions in which the examples given are much more complex than in my scenario.

I have a simple function that creates an object in the global environment (`global_obj`).

Let's say:

```
my_function <- function(x){
    global_obj <<- x
}
```

How can I set the function to check if `global_obj` exists in the global environment and, if so, to then remove it before proceeding?

I have tried something like this:

```
if(exists("global_obj")){ rm("global_obj"); print("global_obj removed") }
```

And:

```
if(exists("global_obj")){ rm(global_obj); print("global_obj removed") }
```

But receive the error messages:

```
[1] "global_obj removed"
Warning message:
In rm("global_obj") : object 'global_obj' not found
```

And:

```
[1] "global_obj removed"
Warning message:
In rm(global_obj) : object 'global_obj' not found
```

Despite the "success message", the error message implies that `global_obj` was never removed because it couldn't be found.

Some answers suggested pointing `rm()` to the global environment, which makes sense, but this still results in the same outcome.

Finally, I know that `global_obj` will be replaced each time I run `my_function()`, but there is an important reason why I want to remove it each time: **it is to prevent any instances where the function may have completed incorrectly but without any warning**.

As such, this would lead me to believe that the `global_obj` that exists in my global environment is the one from the most recent `my_function()` call when in fact the `global_obj` that I see could have existed from a previous execution of it.

**I want to be certain that the `global_obj` that I see in my global environment is the most recent one.  If the function fails, I expect my environment to be empty.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was - I needed to point `rm()` at the global environment:

```
if(exists("global_obj")) rm("global_obj", envir = globalenv())
```